# Drag preview разные стили

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-n-drop, draggable

Интересует вопрос поведения Drag preview у draggable элементов, в частности, какие свойства влияют на изменения его отображения?

Когда-то превью прозрачное

[image: Drag красный]

Но при изменении некоторых условий (высота, ширина, масштаб окна) превью становится менее прозрачным (см. желтый).

[image: Drag желтый]

Причем, это происходит в лайв режиме. Изменил соотношение сторон браузера, изменилось поведение.
Я попробовал несколько вариантов назначения высоты и ширины:
фиксированные, в зависимости от высоты/ширины окна (vh/vw), но так или иначе, при изменении высоты/ширины или масштаба окна браузер, какой-то из элементов изменяет свое отображение превью.

Возможно, кто-нибудь подскажет правила, по которым происходит изменение стиля?

Не забывайте пример во все окно разворачивать.

```js
let dp200 = document.getElementById("drag-preview-200");
let dp500 = document.getElementById("drag-preview-500");
let preview200 = document.createElement('img');
let preview500 = document.createElement('img');
preview200.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/200.png/09f');
preview500.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/500.png/3f1');



dp200.addEventListener("dragstart", (event)=>{
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(preview200, 150, 150);
console.log();
})

dp500.addEventListener("dragstart", (event)=>{
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(preview500, 150, 150);
console.log();
})
```

```css
.drag-px-small{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.drag-px-big {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.drag-vw{
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: red;
}
.drag-vh {
  width: 25vh;
  height: 25vh;
  background: pink;
}

.drag-vwvh {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  background: tan;

}

.drag-preview {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

#drag-preview-200 {
background: purple;
}

#drag-preview-500 {
background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="drag-px-small" draggable="true">
px: 300x300
</div>
<div class="drag-px-big" draggable="true">
px: 400x400
</div>
<div class="drag-vw" draggable="true">
vw: 25x25 
</div>
<div class="drag-vh" draggable="true">
vh: 25x25 
</div>

<div class="drag-vwvh" draggable="true">
vw/vh: 25x25
</div>
<div class="drag-preview" id="drag-preview-200" draggable="true">
Small custom drag preview / dataTransfer.setDragImage
</div>

<div class="drag-preview" id="drag-preview-500" draggable="true">
Big custom drag preview / dataTransfer.setDragImage
</div>
```

### Примечание

В ходе обсуждения подтвердился факт того, что на разных ОС и разных браузерах поведение dragPreview различается.

- Windows. Firefox. Поведение в FF отличается от поведения в Chrome и
  Opera, в частности, FF начинает добавлять прозрачный градиент при одинаковых условиях, голубой кубик 300х300 пикселей, из исходного примера выше, в FF при 100% масштабе имеет градиент с прозрачностью, в то время как в Opera и Chrome на 300х300 кубе градиента в dragPreview нет.
- Linux. Firefox. Градиент отсутствует полностью. В случае, если элемент драга занимает большУю площадь окна, FF уменьшает размер dragpreview (см. картинку ниже). При назначении `setDragImage` dragPreview появляется без градиента и без размера для больших элементов.

ОС:Linux, Браузер: Firefox, Размер элемента: 400x400xp, масштаб 150%
[image: Linux_FF_400x400_150%]

ОС:Linux, Браузер: Firefox, Размер setDragImage: 500x500xp, масштаб 100%. При увеличении масштаба окна браузера поведение не изменяется. Увеличение масштаба окна браузера влияет на увеличение масштаба dragPreview. 
[image: Linux_FF_setDragImage500x500_100%]

ОС:Linux, Браузер: Firefox, Размер setDragImage: 500x500xp, масштаб 170%.
[image: sdi_170pr_Linux_FF]

- Linux. Opera. Градиент отсутствует полностью. DragPreview всегда отображается по размерам исходного элемента. При увеличении масштаба окна отображение не изменяется.
- Linux. Opera. Масштабирование окна не применяется к масштабированию картинки, назначенной через setDragImage (см пример ниже)

ОС:Linux, Браузер: Opera, Размер элемента 400х400px, масштаб 175%. Масштабирование окна браузера влияет на размер dragPreview
[image: 400x400_175pr_Linux_Opera]

ОС:Linux, Браузер: Opera, Размер setDragImage 500х500px, масштаб 175%. Масштабирование окна браузера НЕ влияет на dragPreview.
[image: sdi_500x500_175pr_Linux_Opera]

### Вывод

Судя по всему, поведение dragPreview реализуется в каждом браузере для каждой операционной системы по разному. Как следствие, независимо от того, используется `setDragImage` или нет, реальной возможности контроля отображения dragPreview, при использовании html `draggable`, нет, и во всех браузерах/операционных системах dragPreview будет отображаться с некоторыми отличиями.

Тем не менее, некоторые из результатов обсуждения могут быть кому-либо интересны и полезны.

Comment: Это поведение одинаково во всех браузерах?

Comment: Проверил в chrome и opera поведение одинаковое (синий и розовый без прозрачности) . В FF только розовый без прозрачности, все остальные с прозрачностью. Закрепил в шапку пример. Судя по всем, браузеры ориентируется по меньшей из сторон окна. Условно, если ширина, меньше высоты, то размеры блока не больше X% от ширины. Если высота меньше ширины, то блок должен быть не больше X% от ширины. В целом, хотелось бы более точные данные узнать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [официальным рекомендациям HTML5.2 от W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/editing.html#the-drag-data-store) отображение картинок является опциональной функцией:

> - The following information, used to generate the UI feedback during the drag:
>
>   - User-agent-defined default feedback information, known as the drag data store default feedback.
>   - Optionally, a bitmap image and the coordinate of a point within that image, known as the drag data store bitmap and drag data store hot spot coordinate.

К примеру, в Хроме и Сафари на MacOS нет градиента прозрачности не зависимо от размеров.

Градиент, который присутствует на Windows, отчасти показывает координаты точки за которую и происходит перетаскивание.

Немного информации также даёт раздел [Drag operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) на MDN:

> ### Setting the drag feedback image
>
> When a drag occurs, a translucent image is generated from the drag target (the element the "dragstart" event is fired at)...

Так или иначе полагаться на это поведение не стоит, поскольку оно не стандартизировано. В случаях, когда это поведение имеет значение стандарт предусматривает использование [`DataTransfer.setDragImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage)

> `dataTransfer.setDragImage(element, x, y)`
>   Uses the given element to update the drag feedback, replacing any previously specified feedback.

То же рекомендует и MDN:

> ...you can use setDragImage() to specify a custom drag feedback image.

---

UPD. Такое поведение есть только на Windows. Все картинки размер которых больше 240 пикселей по любой отрисовываются с градиентом.
В 2013 году это значение было [300 пикселей](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18841228/3344612).

Действительно, к сожалению, картинки поставленные через `setDragImage`, тоже подвержены этому. В этом случае стоит использовать javascript для манипуляции перетаскиваемыми объектами.

Answer (score 2):

Единственный вариант, который приходит в голову - это способ отрисовки draggable-элементов GUI операционной системы. По-умолчанию определённые разрешения отрисовывает как в первом случае, с эффектом фокусирования цвета на курсоре при перемещении. Однако если элемент не соответствует каким-либо пропорциям относительно экрана, подобная отрисовка становится либо плохо выглядящей, либо требующей больше ресурсов. Поэтому элемент становится просто прозрачным.

Comment: Проблема в том, что превью изменяется относительно окна браузера, а не экрана.