# Кастомизация элемента при переносе на react, (Drag and Drop)

Tags: css, reactjs, drag-n-drop

Создаю на странице функционал drag and drop на react. Использую стандартное событие onDragStart. Проблема заключается в том что мне надо кастомизировать элемент при переносе. Но я не могу до него достучатся. Кто-то может подсказать способ это сделать, возможно мне стоит использовать определенную библиотеку?

Answer (score 0):

Кастомизация drag preview для [html drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) сильно ограничена, да и поведение для всех браузеров отличается, в частности, прозрачность, масштабирование, курсоры и т.п.
Возможно, по поведению html dnd, найдете что-то полезное в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081746/drag-preview-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8) вопросе.

Если нужны более детальные средства кастомизации dnd, то лучше использовать компоненты [react-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd) или [react-beautiful-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd)